# A line graph is not displayed in a program that draws data and draws a graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a program that reads the data and draws a graph accordingly.

Data format is .txt file

Data loading and reading seem to work fine, but the graph does not seem to be displayed due to some error in the plot creation function.

Please tell me the reason. Thank you.

6 means the number of data types and the letters mean the names of data types.

[image]

```
#########.txt#################

6
Temp
Humid
Pressure
Alti
O3
OMG
OGM 
13.3
33.4
43.2
23.1
43.4
54.5
23.3
43.2
54.0
23.0
54.8
34.6
54.8
34.5

#########.txt#################


import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PySimpleGUIWx as sg


# 파일 불러오기 대화상자 생성
def create_file_dialog():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("데이터 파일 선택:")],
        [sg.Input(key="-FILE-"), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Button("데이터 그래프 생성", key="-PLOT-")]
    ]
    window = sg.Window("데이터 파일 불러오기", layout)
    return window


# 데이터 파일에서 데이터 읽기
def read_data_from_file(file_path):
    data_names = []
    data_values = []
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
    num_types = int(file.readline().strip())
    for _ in range(num_types):
        data_names.append(file.readline().strip())
    for line in file:
        try:
            data_values.append(float(line.strip()))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    num_values = len(data_values)
    num_remaining = num_values % num_types
    if num_remaining != 0:
        num_values -= num_remaining

    data_values = data_values[:num_values]
    data = list(zip(data_names, data_values))
    return data


# 데이터 그래프 생성
def create_plot(selected_data, *data_values):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

    colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue',          'purple', 'brown', 'gray', 'pink', 'cyan']
    for i, values in enumerate(data_values):
    color = colors[i % len(colors)]

    if isinstance(values, float):
        values = [int(values)]  # Convert a single float value     to a list of integers
    else:
        values = [int(val) for val in values]  # Convert float values to integers

    x = range(len(values))  # X-axis as the index of the values
    y = values  # Y-axis as the data values

    plt.plot(x, y, color=color, label=selected_data[i])

    plt.xlabel("데이터 인덱스")
    plt.ylabel("데이터 값")
    plt.title("데이터 그래프")
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()




# GUI 실행
def run_gui():
    window = create_file_dialog()
    while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "-PLOT-":
        file_path = values["-FILE-"]
        if not file_path:
            sg.popup("파일을 선택하세요.", title="오류")
            continue

        try:
            data = read_data_from_file(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            sg.popup(f"파일 열기 오류: {e}", title="오류")
            continue

        data_types = [data_type for data_type, _ in data]
        num_types = len(data_types)

        if num_types > 10:
            sg.popup("데이터 종류의 개수는 10을 넘을 수 없습니다.", title="오류")
            continue

        layout = [[sg.Checkbox(data_type, key=data_type, default=True)] for data_type in data_types]
        layout.append([sg.Button("그래프 생성", key="-CREATE_PLOT-")])

        data_window = sg.Window("데이터 선택", layout)

        while True:
            data_event, data_values = data_window.read()

            if data_event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
                break
            elif data_event == "-CREATE_PLOT-":
                selected_data = [data_type for data_type, selected in data_values.items() if selected]
                selected_values = [value for data_type, value in data if data_type in selected_data]
                create_plot(selected_data, *selected_values)

        data_window.close()

    window.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_gui()
```

Comment: The code you have shared looks fine, so the data reading is probably the issue. Are you converting the numbers to floats? Please share the data reading code. You should also fix the indentation error in the pasted code.

Comment: Also, you can save a plot using `plt.savefig("filename.png")` rather than taking a screenshot of it.

Comment: @jared Thanks for answering first. I tried converting to float as instructed, but the graph is still not displayed. Is there another solution? (I added entire code)

Comment: Your `read_data_from_file` function has some indentation issues, so I can't tell if it's working properly.

Comment: Have you checked that function returns the expected data in the expected data type?

Comment: This `plt.plot(x, y, marker='*', color=color, label=selected_data[i])` might help. Because you are plotting a line plot, and there is only one point in each line, the point is not easily shown. The `marker` parameter makes the point obvious.

Comment: @jared As you said, there was a problem with the read_data_from_file(file_path) function. my code trying to change the data type name of the string type to a float type, but I didn't know if there was an error because of the try and excpet statements. Thank you for answer :)

Comment: Today's lesson: Never catch an exception and just ignore it (i.e. `pass` or `continue`).

Comment: @Omnibus1016 Since there isn't much for others to learn from this question, I'd recommend deleting it. No reason to leave an unanswered question. Just adds to the growing issue on stack overflow.